Sidewalk categorization: Erasing features near or on top of others
I am trying to rank roads with the best pedestrian access in a small town. Green indicates that there are two sidewalks on either side of the road (the best), yellow indicates that there is one sidewalk on a side of the road (moderate), red indicates that there is no sidewalk on either side of the road (the worst). The data is coming from multiple sources, making it difficult to work with. I have been able to map the areas as best and moderate, seen in figure 1. However, when I try to bring in another layer to show the areas with the worst pedestrian access it doesn't work perfectly because they don't align (figure 2). As you can see, there are places where the red is seeping out from under the yellow (see the far left side of the map). How can I clean this map up so there is no red pooling around the other lines?
 
